# Usage of Ord for binary tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I am currently working on an assignment where I have to create a binary tree in Haskell.

We have to use the following data type definition:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

A tree with the value Nil is an empty (ordered) tree and a non-empty tree consists of a value and two subtrees.

I have to write a function "isOrderedTree" which returns True for an ordered tree and False for an unordered one.

The function is defined like this:

```
isOrderedTree :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isOrderedTree Nil = True
isOrderedTree (Node x Nil Nil) = True
isOrderedTree (Node x (Node y a b) Nil) = x > y && isOrderedTree (Node y a b) && x > getMax (getValues (Node y a b))
isOrderedTree (Node x Nil (Node y a b)) = y > x && isOrderedTree (Node y a b) && x < getMin (getValues (Node y a b))
isOrderedTree (Node x (Node y a b) (Node z c d)) = x > y && x < z && isOrderedTree (Node y a b) && isOrderedTree (Node z c d) && x > getMax (getValues (Node y a b)) && x < getMin (getValues (Node z c d))
```

My problem is that the following function invocation does not work:

```
isOrderedTree Nil
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘isOrderedTree’ prevents the constraint ‘(Ord a0)’ from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
These potential instances exist:
 instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
 instance Ord Ordering 
 instance Ord Integer
```

Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Comment: ~~You don't show how you've tried to use `isOrderedTree`.~~ Whoops, you did, but one couldn't read it due to formatting.

Comment: A side note: this implementation may not be correct, depending on exactly what "ordered" means. For example, is `Node 1 (Node 0 Nil (Node 2 Nil Nil)) Nil` -- which has `2` in the "smaller" subtree of the `1` node -- ordered or not? What does your function say for this case?

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, I have now adressed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a concrete type for `Nil`, even though the particular type is not important.

```
-- All of the following should return True
isOrderedTree (Nil :: Tree ())
isOrderedTree (Nil :: Tree Integer)
isOrderedTree (Nil :: Tree Char)
-- etc
```

Comment: Or you can use `-XTypeApplications` from GHC 8 like `isOrderedTree @() Nil` or `isOrderedTree @Int Nil`. It is shorter than explicit type specification.